# Linux Doesn't Respond to SYN on ESTABLISHED connection

Tags: tcp, linux-kernel

So I have a remote device using a Lantronics XPort module connecting to a VPS. They establish a TCP connection and everything is great. The server ACKs everything.

At some point the remote device stops transmitting data. 30 seconds goes by.

The device then starts sending SYN packets as if trying to establish a new connection. The device is configured to maintain a connection to the server, and it always uses the same source port. (I realize this is bad, but it is hard for me to change)

The server sees a SYN packet from the same (source ip, source port), so the server thinks the connection is ESTABLISHED. The server does not respond to the SYN packet.

1. Why does the server not respond with ACK as described in Figure 10 in RFC 793? ( https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc793.txt )
2. How can I get the server to kill the connection or respond with an ACK?

It could be the case that during that 30 second silence, the device is waiting for an ACK from the server, and that ACK was dropped somewhere along the line. In this case, I think it should retransmit.

Server is running Ubuntu with kernel 3.12.9-x86_64-linode37

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first suggestion is change the client to use the same connection or to gracefully close the connection before re-opening.

As you DO NOT have control over client and all that can do is on server, you can try this:

Configure keep-alive to be sent after 10 secs of silence and probe only once. If client does not respond, server closes the connection. By doing this, the server should be in listening mode again within 10 seconds of silence without client responding. You can play with the following sysctl's and arrive at optimal values.

net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 10

net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 1

======

Also, regarding missing-ack that you have mentioned in your question, TCP takes care of those things. 30 seconds is too long a time for the first re-transmission from sender. If client/device does not get an ack after 30 seconds, it will/should not try to open a new connection. If you are seeing that, it is an insane-TCP stack at the client. What is that device and which OS/TCP-stack is it using?

Comment: Thank you. The part I missed here is that the keep-alive behavior is not the default. At socket creation, you must use setsockopt to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

it is kernel version has different behavior,  ignore any syn packet in  kernel 3.12.9-x86_64. but server ack a ack packet, client receive the ack resent rst, and  sent new syn in kernel 4.9.0.
[incoming-tcp-syns-possibilities](https://serverfault.com/questions/607624/incoming-tcp-syns-possibilities)

[TCP packets ignored on ESTABLISHED connection](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1441833)